# CSS with React Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, global-variables

So I am running react native with classic CSS. I am trying to set the color scheme by setting up color variables with CSS. Starting with header:

header.module.css:

```
:root {
  --brand-Black: '#0A0908';
  --secondary-Black: '#27262C';
  --brand-Blue-light: '#86BBD8';
  --brand-Green: '#247B9F';
  --brand-Gold: '#DBAD06';
  --brand-Blue-dark: '#005AA4';
  --brand-Blue: '#4392F1';
  --brand-Red: '#DB2955';
  --brand-Red-dark: '#831933';
  --brand-Grey: '#999999';
}

.text-default {
  color: blue;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 63px;
  line-height: 64px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 147px;
  padding-top: 24px;
  background-color: var(--brand-Blue-light);
}
```

I grab the container class of container but the color does not show up. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Here is the header.js file too:

```
    import React from 'react';
import {Image, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import styles from '../../assets/styles/Header.module.css';
import colors from '../../config/colors';

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title} >{this.props.name}</Text>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={{
            uri: this.props.image,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not possible. you have to write your styles as objects, typically done with "StyleSheet.create({})": https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet

Comment: Did not get what you mean, sorry. Is it not possible to write custom variables in classic CSS?

Comment: not like classic css. you can still save colors as variables and export/import them. then you can use those variables to make sure you always use the same colors globally.